# Does JOSSO provide any user management itself?

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, josso

I've been asked to use [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home) to provide SSO to a set of web apps that currently all have their own authentication and authorization systems.

Part of this project is creating the master source of user information and permissions including administrative tasks like creating users, assigning permissions, deleting users, resetting passwords, etc.

My impression of working with JOSSO so far is that it simply provides the bridge between some master authentication source (LDAP, RDBMS, etc.) and the end applications but that it does not actually provide management of the master authentication.

The [JOSSO 1.7 Release Notes](http://www.atricore.com/news/josso_1_7_released.html) mention a new "Ajax user management application" which sounds like it might be what I need, but I can't any further documentation about it.

Does JOSSO provide any user management itself?  Is there an SSO system that does?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to provide such management. In the mentioned release notes it is written more clearly as "Offers web-based management of user and roles".

The topic is also demonstrated in the [JOSSO 2 tutorial](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Video+Tutorial+-+Internet+SSO+Rollout+using+JOSSO2), where an internal "Identity Vault" is created and users are configured in the JOSSO management application.

Comment: I am specifically looking for support in version 1.x, but I'll check this out.